# How to skip to next Animation in AnimatorSet

Tags: android, android-studio, android-animation, objectanimator, animatorset

I am building a game that uses animations of images sequentially (using `ObjectAnimator`s in an `AnimatorSet`). I would like to skip to the next animation if certain conditions are met. How would I go about this? Thanks!

Edit:

Here's what I have tried so far using `setCurrentPlayTime`:

```
enemyAnimation.setCurrentPlayTime(11000);
```

Since each animation cycle is 11000 ms, I am essentially skipping each animation. However, this is a very hard-coded method and not flexible if I want to add more enemies or animations.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please show some code

Comment: Yep, just added what I've tried. Lmk if you need anything else.